# DRF: How to get object in ModelSerializer.validate()

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need to get the current object in ModelSerializer.validate() when it's being updated(not created)

Currently, I'm using `self._args[0]`

```py
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('id', 'Username')

    def validate(self, data):
        current_user = self._args[0]  # <--
```

It's something like `self.get_object()` in ViewSet

I wonder if there is a better way to get what I want, any idea? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ***`.instance`*** attribute

Example:

```
class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = ('id', 'Username')

    def validate(self, data):
        instance = self.instance


# initialization
s = UserInfoSerializer(data={"foo": "bar"}, instance=model_instance)
```